# android set exit icon to item menu

Tags: android

i have a menu contains of one item (item to exit application), i want to set an icon to that item, i am working like this (`exit is the name of my icon`);

```
<item android:id="@+id/bexitMenuExit"
        android:title="Exit"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="@drawable/exit"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        ></item>
```

but i didn't got the icon on the item, and i didn't find `android:icon` for exit, i found for help, setting ... , but not for exti

Comment: If doesn't have means. Just copy your own exit icon into your drawable. And, set as `android:icon="@drawable/youriconname"`

Comment: @SpK i did that already , check this `@drawable/exit`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it doesn't work means - Push a own exit icon to your project  `drawable`'s any of folder and use like below code for your icon

`android:icon="@drawable/youriconname"`

Otherwise try this icon -

[image]

If you want to use above icon. Like this code

```
<item android:id="@+id/bexitMenuExit"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
      android:title="Exit"/>
```

And have a look at [Android Drawables](https://web.archive.org/web/20150625025354/http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com:80/) you can find lot of android icons.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
@drawable/ic_menu_prefrences
```

This is what I would try:

```
<item android:id="@+id/bexitMenuExit"
    android:title="Exit"
    android:alphabeticShortcut=""
    android:icon="@drawable/exit"
    ></item>
```

Comment: I'm not at my android dev kit right now, can't test it, but I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: and why the icon doesn't appear?

Comment: Put @drawable/exit for Icon.  Alphabetic shortcut looks like it's supposed to be a string anyway

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for something like this `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"`

Answer (score 0):

easy just do like this or copy it, make sure you have the icon named as (exit)

> ```
>     android:title="Exit" android:icon="@drawable/exit"/>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just answering didn't found any exit button icon part, [Google asset-studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/) is a great place where you can find the most used android icons, or even better generate your own icons in all drawable analysis for several themes.